# Python store lists with single key and two values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use the code portion below

```
num_item = 3
for i in range(1,num_item+1):
   list(itertools.combinations(range(0,num_item), i))
```

to generate a list of combinations

```
[[(0,), (1,), (2,)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)], [(0, 1, 2)]]
```

I'd like to make these combinations as key for two values: kvalue and kweight, as shown in example below

```
key 1 : (0,)   , value 1 : kvalue = 8  kweight = 4
key 2 : (1,)   , value 2 : kvalue = 10  kweight = 5
key 3 : (2,)   , value 3 : kvalue = 15  kweight = 8
```

1. Is there any good data structure to store the data above?
2. How can I convert (0,) into a key (of string) ?
3. I'd also need to sort the list by kweight later on, is it possible to use a data structure which can call some python sort function?

---

EDITED: I think I should extend the example above. I want to store, let say, (0,1,2) as key 7, with  2 values for this key : kvalue = -1, and kweight = 9

```
key 1 : (0,)   , value 1 : kvalue = 8  kweight = 4
key 2 : (1,)   , value 2 : kvalue = 10  kweight = 5
key 3 : (2,)   , value 3 : kvalue = 15  kweight = 8
key 4 : (0, 1) , value 4 : kvalue = 18  kweight = 9
key 5 : (0, 2) , value 5 : kvalue = -1  kweight = 4
key 6 : (1, 2) , value 6 : kvalue = -1  kweight = 5
key 7 : (0, 1, 2) , value 7 : kvalue = -1  kweight = 9
```

Comment: So, something like `{(0,) : (8, 4)}` ?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want a dictionary from `int`s to tuples (int, int)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any good data structure to store the data above?

[`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

> How can I convert (0,) into a key (of string) ?

You don't actually need to. Since `(0,)` is a tuple and tuples are hashable, it can be used as a key directly.

> I'd also need to sort the list by kweight later on, is it possible to use a data structure which can call some python sort function?

```
sorted(dictofnamedtuples.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('kweight'))
```

Comment: I check namedtuple. How can I set "key" for into namedtuple?

Let say, 

from collections import namedtuple
Bag = namedtuple('Bag', 'v w')
pt1 = Bag(8, 4)
pt2 = Bag(10, 5)

How can I set (0,)  as key for pt1, and (1,)  as key for pt2?

Comment: You wouldn't. You'd use them as the key in a dict with the namedtuple instance instances as values.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a nested dict or create a value object.

```
{0:{'value':1, 'kvalue':8, 'kweight':4}}
```

or

```
class Value:

    def __init__(self, value, kvalue, kweight):
        self.value = value
        self.kvalue = kvalue
        self.kweight = kweight

{0:Value(1,8,4)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are basically generating 2^n - 1 numbers where n is the num_item..
So you can use bit manipulations to get the above result.

iterate i from 0 to 2^n - 1:
find binary of i:
check each set bit and the position of that bit(starting from 1) will give you the combination you want.